# Wifi doesn't work on Acer E1-531

Tags: drivers, wireless, 16.04

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 today on my laptop and I was unable to get the WiFi to work (LAN works). Ubuntu recognizes the WiFi NIC (made by intel), lists all the WiFi networks and allows me to connect to my router. Ubuntu gets an IP and the rest of the settings. Sometimes it is able to ping the router by IP right after it starts, but it is unable to ping any other IP (checked route -n, gateway OK) and after a while it can't even ping the router. Even when it pings the router it cannot make a TCP connection to it. For now I can only connect to the internet over Ethernet port.

From the other side, my routers sees that my laptop is connected (MAC address and given IP address are listed), but I cannot ping the laptop from my desktop PC and I know I was able to do this while I had windows on laptop.

I'm not new to Linux (or networks), but I'm not very experienced with any hardware related issues, so any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b5] (rev 10)
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [1025:0647]
Kernel driver in use: tg3
Kernel modules: tg3

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 105 [8086:0894] (rev c4)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 105 BGN [8086:0022]

Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Typed this by hand, sorry if there are typos.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to disable 802.11n protocol by this command

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"
```

It will be applied after a reboot.